# Loop through first 3 item in array JavaScript(react)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, loops, for-loop

For example I have 5 items:

```
const items = [
{id: 1, name: 'book', price: 50},
{id: 2, name: 'phone', price: 450},
{id: 3, name: 'fish', price: 80},
{id: 4, name: 'apple', price: 5},
{id: 5, name: 'pen', price: 2},
]
```

When we use map method like this:

```
{items.map( item => (
 <div> {item.name} {item.price} </div>
)}
```

We show all the items;

But I want to show **just** 3 first of that items

How can I do it?(using **map** method Or **for** method Or other methods)

Comment: how about `items.slice(whatever).map(...)`?

Comment: [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) -> [Second result](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20array%20only%20first%20elements%20site%3Astackoverflow.com)

Comment: To avoid closed questions and downvotes, please make sure stackoverflow is the last place you look for an answer, not the first ;) googling "js get part of an array" gives Array.slice as first result, at least for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

```
{items.slice(0,3).map( item => (
 <div> {item.name} {item.price} </div>
)}
```

```js
const items = [
{id: 1, name: 'book', price: 50},
{id: 2, name: 'phone', price: 450},
{id: 3, name: 'fish', price: 80},
{id: 4, name: 'apple', price: 5},
{id: 5, name: 'pen', price: 2},
]

const first3Items = items.slice(0,3);
console.log(first3Items);
```

Comment: @Andreas sorry about that, that's my mistake. I updated it. Thanks for your reminder.